# An example for a non-precompact minimal topological group.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Do you have an example of a non-precompact minimal topological group?

A topological group $(G,\mathcal T)$ is said to be minimal iff it is Hausdorff and for any compatible Hausdorff topology $\mathcal S$ on $G$, we have:
$$\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal T\to\mathcal S=\mathcal T$$

I think Ivan Prodanov proved all abelian minimal topological groups are precompact. So the example needs to be non-abelian.

precompactness is defined with left topological group uniformity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there was an article “Every minimal abelian group is precompact” [PS] by Ivan Prodanov and Luchesar Stojanov. About 15 years ago my teacher gave me this paper. As I remember, he told to me Prodanov and Stojanov searched for the proof for ten years.

A simple example of a non-precompact minimal topological group should be ${\bf SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ (see part 7 and, especially, section 7.4 of the book [DPS] by Dikran Dikranjan, Ivan Prodanov, and Luchesar Stojanov). Also A.I. Costash, and Mikhail Ursul in [CU] constructed examples of non-compact locally compact minimal groups.

Some of our investigation is closely related with minimal topological groups. So, if you have any questions about them, feel free to ask. :-)

*References*

[CU] A.I. Costash, M.I. Ursul. *Examples of minimal topological groups*

[DS] Dikranjan D., Prodanov I., Stoyanov L. Topological Groups. Marcel Dekker, New-York, 1990

[PS] I. Prodanov, L.N. Stojanov, *Every minimal abelian group is precompact*, C. R. Acad. Bulgar. Sci. – 1984. – **37**, #1.

[Here](http://webfile.ru/6487903) they are: paper [CU], book [DS], and the first page of the paper [PS], which my teacher gave me. :-)

Comment: I corrected some grammar. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Thanks. I basically think in Russian, which has a syntax structure and even a “semantic” structure different from English, and I never deeply studied languages, because they are poorly formalized. :-) Thus there should be a lot of errors in my texts when I write them without a consultation with a grammar book. :-)

Comment: The paper [PS] is [here](http://webfile.ru/6488095). But I think that it is better to read the proof of precompactness of all minimal abelian topological groups from Section 2.7 of book [DPS], because paper [PS] is only the last segment of the long way and its proof is based on results from previous papers.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: What does *Precompact* mean?

Comment: A topological group $G$ is precompact if for each neighborhood $U$ of the unit of the group $G$ there exists a finite subset $F$ of $G$ such that $UF=FU=G$.